# Why does page navigation not work here?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, categories, posts

```
    <?php
/**
* Template Name: Blog page
* Description: The blog page
*/
get_header(); ?>


<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div class="postblog">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

    <span class="postdetails">
    <?php the_time ('j F, Y'); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="bullet">&bull;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Posted in:&nbsp;<?php the_category(', '); ?>
    </span>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <div class="fb">
    <?php if(function_exists("wpfblike")) echo wpfblike(); ?>
    </div>

    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>


</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Whenever I try to use WP_Paginate or Pagenavi with this, it refuses to show up, no matter what I try to use I cannot get page navigation. I have 5 posts and only three are showing (as per the code above) so how do I get to the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [next_posts_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) and [previous_posts_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_posts_link)?

```
<?php
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
query_posts("showposts=3&paged=$page");
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
// display your post
<?php endwhile; ?>
// display navigation
<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&larr; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &rarr;') ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does work, but how come I cannot get the plugins to work like this?

Comment: Which wordpress version are you using?

Comment: Check out this link, might be useful: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-paginate-no-previous-or-next-links and this one http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-get-wp-paginate-to-work-on-singlephp